# How to lock some thread using semaphores with OR premitive?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, semaphore

I'm considering an example to evaluate my question further. Consider three threads, T_1, T_2 and T_3.

- If T_2 cannot execute until T_1 has finished its main segment then I'll simply make place a semwait() in the beginning of T_2 and will place semsignal() of same semaphore.
- If T_2 cannot execute until T_1 AND T_3 have finished their main code segment then I'll simply make T_2 wait for two semsignal() functions each at the end of T_1 and T_3.

But what if T_2 cannot execute  until T_1 OR T_3 have finished their main code segment? If I make it wait on some OR function it will likely get blocked on first expression without even testing second one incase T_1 does not allow it to run but T_3 does. So my question is that how can I make it wait for such condition?

Comment: I don't understand?  T_2 waits on a semaphore, T_1 and T_3 both post a unit whenever they want to.  Whichever posts the unit first allows T2 to run.  Is that not what you want??

Comment: If the threads loop round, then you would need to wait on the semaphore again at the end of T_2 work, before looping back, to purge the unit that came from the thread that did not signal T_2 to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you do like so?

T2

```
...
sem_wait(s1)
```

T1, T3

```
...
mutex_lock(m1)
if (!signaled) {
    sem_signal(s1)
    signaled = true;
}
mutex_unlock(m1)
```

Comment: Don't see much point, really, in the complication?  Just let both threads signal when they can.  One will allow T_2 to run, the other will get left in the semaphore. If required, (eg. because the threads loop around).  T_2 could purge that unit by waiting when it's done it's chunk of work.

Comment: @MartinJames You need do it under lock or reinit semaphore every time, because in other way semaphore counter will run away (because you signaling it in two places while wait only in one). But maybe i just didn't understand what you are saying.